# Connecting to Excel spreadsheet through ArcPy giving ERROR 000582

Tags: arcpy, modelbuilder, kernel-density, error-000582

My ultimate goal is to automate kernel density analysis on xy data from a table. I am trying to learn Python but I am very new. I built a simple model to take table data and display xy data. When I attempt to export the model as a Python script, the script fails. I do not have a programming background but I have programmers available to me.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# test.py
# Created on: 2014-02-12 13:14:37.00000
#   (generated by ArcGIS/ModelBuilder)
# Description: 
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Import arcpy module
import arcpy


# Local variables:
Input_Table = "C:\\Users\\cbriglia\\Desktop\\GIS\\Worksheets\\accidents_jan_2013.xls\\Sheet1$"
Sheet1__Layer = "Sheet1$_Layer"
Ouput_Feature_Class = "C:\\Users\\cbriglia\\Desktop\\GIS\\Shapefiles\\acc_jan_2013_builder.shp"

# Process: Make XY Event Layer
arcpy.MakeXYEventLayer_management(Input_Table, "longitude", "latitude", Sheet1__Layer, "GEOGCS['GCS_North_American_1983_CSRS',DATUM['D_North_American_1983_CSRS',SPHEROID['GRS_1980',6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]];-400 -400 1000000000;-100000 10000;-100000 10000;8.98315284119521E-09;0.001;0.001;IsHighPrecision", "")

# Process: Copy Features
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(Sheet1__Layer, Ouput_Feature_Class, "", "0", "0", "0")
```

*Runtime error  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 19, in    File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 6348, in MakeXYEventLayer     raise e ExecuteError: ERROR 000582: Error occurred during execution.*

Comment: I note you are using Evil Excel, the source of many problems! Is your first row the field headers? Remove all unusually characters, don't start a field with a number and skim through your data to make sure there are no mysterious blank rows or a change in data type.

Comment: I also, just personally, would change the name of the Sheet1__Layer from "Sheet1$_Layer" to Sheet1_Layer or just anything without a special character.  As the comment above notes, ArcGIS can be picky about special characters, so minimize their use as much as possible.

Comment: Thank you. Would you recommend going with CSV?

Comment: I believe it was the special character. It works now.

Comment: @Chris, you should go ahead and leave a detailed answer of what you found so that future readers of this question will not have to go through the same struggle as you.  In a couple of days, you can mark the "checkmark" next to you answer as "Accepted" to close out this question.  Glad you found your own solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that there can be no spaces or special characters in output file names when using Python. I removed the special character and the script worked.